# An application of Fubini theorem from Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, lebesgue-integral

I am supposed to integrate the function $f(x,y)= \exp(-y^2)$over the region $[0,1]\times[x,1]$.

I know I can take the double integral for each $x$ and $y$ from Fubini’s theorem, but I am stuck with the error function after doing so and I strongly believe that I am missing something.

Comment: What is this error function?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Using Fubini, you can perform the integration as an iterated integral:
$$
\int_{x=0}^1\left(\int_{y=x}^1 \exp(-y^2)\,dy\right)\,dx\tag1
$$
Written this way, where you integrate over $y$ first, leads to the error function. Instead, swap the order of integration (which is permitted by Fubini), so that you are integrating over $x$ first. To see what the limits of integration should be, write $f(x,y)$ as
$$
f(x,y)= \exp(-y^2)I_A(x,y)$$
where $A$ is the region in the plane $\{(x,y): 0\le x\le1\ \text{and}\ x\le y\le 1\}$ , so $A$ is the triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,1)$, $(0,1)$.

Comment: After the first iteration of integration after x, do I have to apply the region restrictions on y again? So that the exp(-y^2) disappears?

Comment: The expression becomes $\int_{0}^{1}\big(\int_{0}^{y}e^{-y^2}dx \big)dy$, right?

Comment: @Alex Your expression is correct. After the inner integral is done, what remains is an integral over $y$ from $y=0$ to $y=1$. The $\exp(-y^2)$ doesn't disappear, but the inner integral contributes another factor that makes the outer integral tractable.

Comment: Yep thanks I got $\frac{1-e^{-1}}{2}$ in the end

Comment: @Alex You got it.

Comment: @grand_chat thanks a lot!

Comment: @grand_chat yep thanks for the help